# Why does this snippet allow Typescript to infer a generic from a "parent" function?

Tags: typescript

There appears to be an undocumented feature which allows functions to infer a type from a function in which they are passed as an argument.

I'm trying to understand why this works, and if it's intentional.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Given a `Model`, then with a generic `update` and `apply` function, I can infer a type from `apply` when using the result of `update` as an argument with the trick `T extends infer U ? U : never`:

```js
interface Model {
    foo: number
    bar: string
}

function apply<T>(fn: (t: T) => T) {};

function whyDoesThisWork() {

    function update<T>(u: T extends infer U ? Partial<U> : never) { return (t: T) => ({ ...t, ...u }) };

    // Somehow, Typescript is able to infer that we want Model to be the generic supplied for update
    apply<Model>(update({ foo: 1 }));

}

function thisDoesntWorkForObviousReasons() {

    function update<T>(u: Partial<T>) { return (t: T) => ({ ...t, ...u }) }

    // update infers T as { foo: 1 }, because that makes sense
    apply<Model>(update({ foo: 1 }));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior occurs because of [Contextual Typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).

The "trick" can be extracted to a helper typed named `DontInfer`:

```js
type DontInfer<T> = T extends infer S ? S : never;
```

When `DontInfer` is used in a generic function signature, `T` will not be inferred where it is used. From my example, the generic argument `u` can be said to be of the shape `Partial<T>`, but `T` will not be inferred by `u`:

```js
function update<T>(u: DontInfer<Partial<T>>) { return (t: T) => ({ ...t, ...(u as Partial<T>) }) };
```

This means that the `update` function will not be able to infer `T` if it is used on its own:

```js
// T is inferred to be `unknown`
update({ foo: 1 })
```

But when used in a context, T is able to be inferred:

```js
// T is inferred to be Model
setState<Model>(update({ foo: 1 }));
```

`DontInfer` works for this purpose because it [defers evaluating unresolved conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546).

Comment: I elaborated on how this functions here: https://dev.to/davidshortman/weird-ts-types-using-contextual-typing-and-deferred-inference-to-plan-an-alien-conquest-bm8